# How to find the Ressource Path/Ressource itself in swift with on demand resources

Tags: swift, objective-c, flutter, xcode, on-demand-resources

I have a flutter application which is an audio guide. But i have the audio files in many languages so i want to use on demand resources on the IOS side. I opened the Runner from the ios folder in Xcode and added the assets and gave them tags. The audio files are of the type wav.
[image: the tags][image: The asset folder]
But when requesting the images with the tag `german` i get no results.

```swift
private func getDownloadRessources(tag: String, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    let resourceRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: [tag])
    resourceRequest.beginAccessingResources { (error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            // Handle the error.
            print("Error accessing resources: \(error)")
            result(FlutterError(code: "RESOURCE_ERROR", message: "\(error) tag:\(tag)", details: error.localizedDescription))
        } else {
            guard let resourceURL = resourceRequest.bundle.url(forResource: nil, withExtension: "wav") else {
                print("Resource not found for tag: \(tag)")
                result(FlutterError(code: "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND", message: "Resource not found for tag: \(tag)", details: nil))
                return
            }
            print("Resource URL: \(resourceURL.absoluteString)")
            result(resourceURL.absoluteString)
        }
        resourceRequest.endAccessingResources()
    }
}
```

In the code i have the tag `german` which is given, but the `resourceRequest.bundle.url` does still not find the ressource audio.

I tried to get the path of Bundle.main and looked there for the audio but that didn't work. I gave the name to the method and it did still not find it. I looked inside the path of the resourcerequest bundle but did still not find the audio files. I tried with the Bundle.main method but still no luck in finding the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with NSDataAsset. When i pass it the name of the file i get it back and then can either save it with FileManager in Swift or send the bytes to flutter.

```
 if let asset = NSDataAsset(name:"audio1") {
                print(asset)
                result(asset.data)
            } else {
                print("Resource not found for tag: \(tag)")
                                 result(FlutterError(code: "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
                                                    message: "Resource not found for tag: \(tag)",
                                                    details: nil))
            }
```

or with

```
if let asset = NSDataAsset(name:"audio1") {
                // Get the directory to save the file
                let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

                // Specify the file name and type
                let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent("audio1.mp3")

                // Write the NSDataAsset to the file
                do {
                    try asset.data.write(to: fileURL)
                    print("File saved to \(fileURL.absoluteString)")
                    result(fileURL.absoluteString)
                } catch {
                    print("Error saving file: \(error)")
                    result(FlutterError(code: "ERROR_SAVING_FILE",
                                        message: "Error saving file: \(error)",
                                        details: nil))
                }
            } else {
                print("Resource not found for tag: \(tag)")
                result(FlutterError(code: "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
                                    message: "Resource not found for tag: \(tag)",
                                    details: nil))
```